# Java can't find my main class

Tags: java, windows

Ok so first off completely new to any sort of programming. I am trying http://www.wikihow.com/Write-Your-First-Program-in-Java. I followed it to the T but in the command prompt every time I type "java HelloWorld" it keeps coming up with "Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld. Why so?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World.");
    }
}
```

And yes I compiled it, there is a `HelloWorld.java` and .class

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\BrianC>dir
 Volume in drive C is Acer
 Volume Serial Number is 08EF-47A2

 Directory of C:\Users\BrianC

10/22/2014  05:59 PM    <DIR>          .
10/22/2014  05:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/19/2014  01:20 PM                83 .atl.properties
12/15/2013  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Contacts
10/24/2014  01:24 AM    <DIR>          Desktop
10/14/2014  06:27 PM    <DIR>          Documents
10/24/2014  12:15 AM    <DIR>          Downloads
08/10/2014  08:13 AM    <DIR>          Dropbox
01/16/2014  07:28 PM    <DIR>          Favorites
10/22/2014  06:35 PM    <DIR>          KAG-Beta
07/15/2014  03:13 PM    <DIR>          Links
12/15/2013  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Music
10/03/2014  09:49 AM    <DIR>          Pictures
04/09/2014  11:37 AM    <DIR>          Saved Games
12/15/2013  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Searches
12/15/2013  05:40 PM    <DIR>          Videos
               1 File(s)             83 bytes
              15 Dir(s)  325,924,110,336 bytes free

C:\Users\BrianC>java HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld

C:\Users\BrianC>
```

Comment: Post your EXACT code here please!

Comment: did you compile it?go to your directory and check is there HelloWorld class file exist or not

Comment: What's the file name that you saved this class in and what command are you using to run?

Comment: Ideally, please post a transcript of your console/shell session too.

Comment: @bcoolbro .class file exist .ok but what is the name of it?

Comment: Have you navigated(in command prompt) to the folder where your file is?

Comment: is there any package name in your program?

Comment: use cd  command to go to the directory containing your HelloWorld.class file and then try java HelloWorld

Comment: Try: 'java -cp . HelloWorld'

Comment: The example you mentioned contains all details even the cd commands too. Did you miss a step?

Comment: @Himanshu Bhardwaj not that I'm aware of

Comment: @frankfg it still says the same thing

Comment: @bcoolbro to clarify things you definitely should post a transcript or snap shot from the console .first type dir and then type your java HelloWorld and post output here.

Comment: Should I be putting my replies in my question or keep using the comments? I've never used this site so I'm not sure

Comment: @getlost 'dir java HelloWorld' or enter after I type dir?

Comment: @bcoolbro no type dir and then enter .then java HelloWorld and hit enter

Comment: @getlost When I do that the first thing that comes up is a directory of C:\Users\MYNAME then typing 'java HelloWorld' comes up with the same error

Comment: @bcoolbro yes .post the a snapshot of your console

Comment: Are you sure you are typing "java -cp . HelloWorld". Bcoz your last command says something else.

Comment: @getlost the site says I can't post a pic could I maybe send you a dropbox link in a PM?

Comment: @bcoolbro don't worry you can copy the console and paste here

Comment: @bcoolbro so it's clear that there is no class file in that directory.only file exist in that directory is .properties file.you should navigate to directory where your class file exist

Comment: @getlost I can tell you the exact location of the Class file if that's what you're looking for

Comment: @bcoolbro you should nevigate to the directory where did you save .java file through the cmd .then type javac command and then type java command .if you are in correct directory you will able to see .class file when you type dir command.

Comment: the easy way is make a directory in your desktop>> open the directory>> create .java file again>> open cmd >> type cd + path of your directory  location. example cd "C:\Users\BrianC\desktop\your  directory" >> then type javac command to compile >>finally type java command to run.you haven't navigate to directory .so there is no class file that's exactly what compiler said

Comment: @fast snail Thank you that worked idk if other people were saying to do that or not but you were the most specific and I think that's what helped if that is the case

Comment: @bcoolbro good luck you

Answer (score 1):

As @frankfg mentioned in the comment , I will not post all details here but this should be enough:

```
C:\TEMP>dir Hell*
 Volume in drive C is YYY
 Volume Serial Number is XXX

 Directory of C:\TEMP

24/10/2014  12:13               426 HelloWorld.class
24/10/2014  12:13               126 HelloWorld.java
               2 File(s)            552 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  140,363,472,896 bytes free



C:\TEMP>java HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld

C:\TEMP>java -cp . HelloWorld
Hello World.
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer .but the problem is op clams that java -cp gives same result

Comment: That's why I asked him to retrace his steps, there are just 1 of the 2 cases OP is falling into:
1.) Working on the wrong dir (HelloWorld.class file is not present in this dir).
2.) some_dir>java -cp . HelloWorld.class , this will also yield the error.

I can't think of any other reason why this error would happen.